# Efficient SQL Schema Design with Odd One-to-Many Relationship

Tags: mysql, database-schema

I am trying to figure out an effective and efficient way to implement the following relationship between two tables, `Lists(ListID, ListName)` and `Items(ItemID, ItemName, Cost, Description, QuantityNeeded, QuantityPurchased)`, in a MySQL database:

> A list can have many items. However, the `Description`, `QuantityNeeded`, and `QuantityPurchased` attributes in the `Items` table are specific to a list. For example, say one item has the attributes `1, Paper Towels, 5.99, NULL, 4, 2`, and another is `2, Paper Towels, 5.99, NULL, 7, 0`. Even though these have the same `ItemName` and `Cost`, they are from different lists.

What is the best way I can go about implementing this? I have thought about adding an attribute `ListID` to the `Items` table so that every item "knows" which list it is a part of, but this could result in really lengthy `WHERE` executions (correct?), and I want this to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: Rule 1:  There's no such thing as a one to many relationship.  Clients will tell you it is, then 6 months later change their mind.  Use joining tables for every relationship in your schema.  It will support 1 to many, many to many or many to 1, you standardize the way you handle establishing relationships in your code, and when the client discovers that "oops, we were wrong, it's a many to many" you are way ahead of them.  It sounds like more work, but once you write your "establish a relationship between these two records in these two tables" function, you are done so it's actually easier.

Comment: @ChrisCaviness So you're saying that I need another table. Would that be along the lines of  `ItemsLists(ItemID, ListID)`, where the two form the key? But would this run into the same issue? Say, for example, I wanted to pull up all the items in a given list. Wouldn't I have to use a `WHERE` clause to search through all the tuples for everything with the given `ListID`? If so, how efficient is that?

Comment: You would use the joining table as your primary source...   SELECT b.* FROM ItemsLists a JOIN items b ON a.ItemID = b.ItemID WHERE a.ListID = 12345  As for efficiency, highly efficient, since your joining table row length is small, and the columns are indexed.  You end up with a small subset of the Item index values you need from the joining table which is then used by the join.

Answer (score 0):

Application relationships are not between tables, they are among values (or entities so identified) and are represented by tables.

Add

```
-- list ListID has member ItemId
-- UNIQUE/PK (itemID)
-- FK (listID) references Lists
-- FK (itemID) references Items
Member(ListID, itemID)
```

Or replace Items by

```
-- list ListID has member ItemId and item ItemId ...
-- UNIQUE/PK (ItemID)
-- FK (ListID) referencing Lists
ItemsX(ListID, ItemID, ItemName, Cost, Description, QuantityNeeded, QuantityPurchased)
```

The former is difficult to constrain in SQL to also have the equivalent of FK Items (ItemID) referencing Member, ie every item must be a member of some list. So typically the latter would be used.

Note that

```
ItemsX = ListID, i.* from Member m join Items i on m.ItemID = i.ItemId
Items = select ItemID,... from ItemsX
Member = select ListID, ItemID from ItemsX
```

If you don't know the options for straightforward models, you don't know enough to worry about "efficiency". You need more design (including constraints) & querying experience. Your situation is addressed in practically any intro to information modeling via orders & order (line) items instead of lists & items.